# .gradle/nodejs/node-v6.7.0-darwin-x64/bin/node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, graphql, apollo

compile graphQL and failed:
.../apollographql/apollo/sample/GithuntFeedQuery.graphql: Cannot query field "species" on type "Query"
:apollo-sample:generateDebugApolloIR FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':apollo-sample:generateDebugApolloIR'.

  > Process 'command '/Users/xulong/Downloads/apollo-android-master/apollo-sample/.gradle/nodejs/node-v6.7.0-darwin-x64/bin/node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: have you found any answer?

Answer (score 1):

Issue in the schema file which is inside the `graphql` folder check the schema file must contain the name of query which you are calling.

For example if you have query

```
query FilmsList{
  filmsList{
        name
  }
}
```

then `filmsList` must be available in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when your `.graphql` file has some errors.

Check for errors by pasting your `.graphql` file contents to Playground or GraphiQL, rectify errors, paste the rectified code back.

Finally, `Clean Project` then `Rebuild Project`.

**Note**: Please ensure that your offline version of `schema.json` present in Android project is updated, else query might run in Playground and still you'll get errors. In simple words, your `schema.json` must have all the fields you're trying to access, as Apollo Client uses it to generate files.